# grub2 menu missing graphic characters

Tags: grub2

I have grub2 working on my Centos7 system but the graphic characters which draw a box around the menu options are missing, and so is any text at the top/title bar.

I've tried changing color_normal color_highlight menu_color_normal menu_color_highlight and they affect text on screen, but the line drawing characters never appear.

My /etc/default/grub contains:

```
GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub2/unicode.pf2"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="20"
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="false"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub2/logo2.png"
menu_color_normal="yellow/black"
menu_color_highlight="black/yellow"
color_normal="white/black"
color_highlight="black/red"
```

Comment: Verify the `GRUB_FONT` location or `GRUB_GFXMODE`  may be using an auto setting that does not work for your display. May require the old `vga=`.  Check out [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks) for some more info.

Comment: The font exists as specified in GRUB_FONT, and graphics mode is working because my background image appears.